# Cannot change cart email within Craft Commerce while logged-in

Tags: users, plugin-craftcommerce, emails

The provided addresses template for the Craft Commerce checkout only shows the email to logged-out users. We need logged-in admin staff to be able to put orders through on behalf of a customer, over the phone. So, I'm showing the email input to logged-in users as well.

When the admin person arrives at the addresses template, the email field is pre-populated with the admin person's address. They replace their email with the customer's email. They submit.

The cart email remains the admin person's email address.

Can anyone think of a workaround for this?

Comment: Will these customers be Craft users or are they guests?

Comment: The customers are guests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is an easy workaround here as you're dealing with logged in user functionality, and by definition that's not really designed to be easy to workaround.

Probably the easiest thing is for the admin to use the 'log in as XXX' functionality, and then complete the order for the customer (assuming the customer had a Craft account which is not, per se, a given with Commerce).  If they're guest customers, the admin should probably jsut log out, complete the order as a guest, and then log back in, basically.

Order entry for admins (via the backend) is on the Commerce plans, though, so a better solution may well appear.